# PHP : Second Function not being called

Tags: php, function, sequence

I am using PHP and want to run 2 functions, one after the other.

These functions are getallmydata() and createCSV()

The code below runs the first function fine but the second function createCSV() is not working. It seems like it is not being called properly.

Is there anything wrong with the structure of my code as both functions work correctly independently? I cannot work this out!

```
<?php

//run this function//
getallmydata();
//then run this function//
createCSV();


function getallmydata(){ 

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/cm/csrest_general.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/cm/csrest_clients.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/cm/csrest_campaigns.php';

$api_key = 'MY API KEY';
$wrap = new CS_REST_General($api_key);
$result = $wrap->get_clients();
$Content = "";

if ($result->was_successful()) {



foreach ($result->response as $client) {

    $client_wrapper = new CS_REST_Clients($client->ClientID, $api_key);
    $client_details_result = $client_wrapper->get();
    $campaigns_result = $client_wrapper->get_campaigns();

    if ($client_details_result->was_successful()) {
        /* This is where the client details will be */
        $client_details = $client_details_result->response;

        echo ('<pre>');
        /*print out the company name*/
        echo "Company Name = " . $client_details->BasicDetails->CompanyName . "<br/>";
        /*print out the company markup*/
        echo "Markup On Delivery = " . $client_details->BillingDetails->MarkupOnDelivery . "<br/>";

        $count = 0;

            if ($campaigns_result->was_successful()) {

                /*print out the latest campaign name of the current campaign*/
                foreach ($campaigns_result->response as $campaign_ob) {

                    echo 'Latest Campaign Name = ' . $campaign_ob->Name . '<br/>';
                    //echo 'Latest Subject = ' . $campaign_ob->Subject . '<br/>';
                    //echo 'Total Recipients = ' . $campaign_ob->TotalRecipients . '<br/>';
                    //echo 'Sent Date = ' . $campaign_ob->SentDate . '<br/>';

                    /*Set content for CSV File*/

                    //$Content .= "This is within the loop \n";



                    $count++;

                    if($count > 0) break;

                }/*end loop*/

            }/*end campaigns if statement*/

        echo ('</pre>');




    } else {
        echo 'Failed with code '.$client_details_result->http_status_code."\n<br /><pre>";
        var_dump($client_details_result->response);
    }

}

} else {
echo 'Failed with code '.$result->http_status_code."\n<br /><pre>";
var_dump($result->response);
echo ('</pre>');
} 


} //end main function




/*create the downloadable csv file*/

function createCSV(){


$FileName = date("d-m-y") . '.csv';


# Titlte of the CSV
//$Content = "Company_Name Markup Campaign_Name Subject Recipients Date \n";

# fill data in the CSV
//$Content .= "\"John Doe\",\"New York, USA\",15,65465464 \n";
$Content .= "Testing The Function Works OK \n";
//$Content .= "This should be another line";
header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
header("Content-length: " . filesize($NewFile)); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"'); 
echo $Content;
exit();  

}//end csv download function







/*end create downloadable .csv file */





?>
```

Comment: You use the variable `$NewFile` in the second function but that variable is not set. Should be `$FileName`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the error: `headers already sent`. (you checked that the second function is called right? You can find it out by placing a `echo` on the first line of the function.)

You are trying to create a CSV page but you are parsing HTML in the first function, so the header is already sent to the client saying that it is a normal HTML page. Remove these echo's in the first function and it should work.

Quote of the PHP manual:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

More info about headers: [PHP header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score -1):

First think I would tell you is
1 you should first write function definition and then you should call a function
i.e

```
function getallmydata(){
 // function code
}

function createCSV(){
   // function code
}

getallmydata();
createCSV();
```

2 . The second thing is that check that is there any white space left in the code out side php code or any o/p that is sent as resonse as because when ever you user `header()` at that if any kind of content other than `header()` is sent as response then `header()` function fails. Try this things and check again.